# What is this big white space and how to remove?

Tags: background-image

Thank you for the help on the white space problem.

Can anyone tell me how to get the grey squares background to extend all the way to the top of the page? I'm clearly not a very good coder at all. I've edited the #page to include this, but it's still leaving it out of the header.

http://www.kvscreative.com/creativene

Thank you!

EDIT2: If someone can help me with these problems and work one-on-one with me, I would be glad to pay. Please e-mail me if you're willing. Thank you - kimberlyvschwartz@yahoo.com

Comment: You should consider accepting some of the answers to your questions if they've helped you.

Comment: Please include screenshots and a small code sample that reproduces the issue (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for more information).

Comment: looks to me like this `min-height: 100%;` in your css #page definition is doing it, and you probably need to remove from the same definition `height: 100%;`

Comment: To increase your chances of getting the attention of users able to answer this questions, you should [edit] them and add the applicable language tag(s).

Comment: If an answer has helped address your question, you should consider accepting it as correct. It's considered both helpful and polite to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs in this CSS declaration in your `style.css`:

```
#page {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -45px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

The `min-height` attribute was set to `100%`, which was causing the large white space to render. Reduce this (preferably to a fixed height) to resolve the issue. The following image depicts how the page is rendered when `min-height` is set to `200px`:

[image]